# How to calculate base voltage and current for NPN transistor required to drive a P-channel MOSFET gate

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, npn, p-channel

I'd like to use a P-channel MOSFET as a on/off switch. I can't pull the gate down directly from my controller because the voltage of the load is 12v, thus I have to use another transistor, as far as I understand. In a few schematics I found I saw that they used N-channel power MOSFETs for that job, but isn't that a waste, since there's very little current that's ever going to pass through it? I happen to have a bunch of BD139s laying around which I'd like to use for this task but I can't find out how to calculate the required voltage and current that I must supply to the base, so that the MOSFET will be operating properly. Here's a sample schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1PXf9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Start with how much collector current you need. Can you figure that out?

Comment: @Andyaka well, with MOSFETs as far as I know there is no current flowing through the gate when used as an on/off switch, so I'm kind of confused. If I take 0 for collector current then that doesn't work out.

Comment: @php_nub_qq So if the FET gate takes zero current (in steady-state neglecting leakage) then what's left?  What about R2?

Comment: Stop worrying about the **voltage**, instead care about the **current** that goes into the base. The voltage across Vbe will be around 0.7 V but that doesn't matter, Vbe will sort itself out provided you make enough **current** flow into the base.

Comment: 0.7 would more like IC=10 mA but in computing R it's only a 10% error relative to 630 mV @Bimpelrekkie so OK

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Compared to the margins we need to account for with regard to the unpredictability of beta (see the datasheet and notice it can vary a factor 2.5 from min to max) that 10% error can be ignored :-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  even if the hFE range was 600:100 in the linear range but the Vbe is still around 600 mV at Ic = 1mA controlled by R2.  This Vbe is dependent on Ib+Ic , independent of hFE . Does that make more sense ?  \$r_{\pi}=26/Ic\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to drive M1 gate fully low (saturate the circuit current through R2),

> Ic (of Q1) = (Vcc - Vce_sat) / R2 = (12V - 0.2V)/10K => 1.2mA

BD139 DC current gain (hfe) can be as low as 25.

> Ic = Ib * hfe, thus, Ib = 1.2mA / 25 = 0.048mA

Since Ib = [(Vgpio - Vbe) / R1] - [Vbe / R3]
**R1 = (Vgpio - Vbe) / (Ib + Vbe/R3) = (3V - 0.7V) / (48uA + 0.7V/10k) = 19492ohm => 15K ohm**

Comment: Resistors shouldn't be saturated.

Comment: @Andyaka, you are right, as always :-) I will correct it.

Answer (score 3):

- to conduct V1/R requires a little more than 1mA which for Ic refers to a standard Vbe of 600 mV which is generally true for many small signal transistors.

Thus choose R3 based on GPIO powered on as an input to ensure FET is off.

Then choose R1 to exceed Vbe of 600 mV by some decent tolerance margin.  We know that Vce(sat) is often specified for Ic/Ib=10 to 50 based on the max hFE in the linear region.

Hint

- I find 10% of max linear hFE is a useful value when your load current is not close the tables in the datasheet when used as a switch rather than Ic/Ib=10, but it depends on what Vce you can tolerate.

  - here you can easily tolerate 10% of 12V or 1.2V which puts you near in linear region of hFE where hFE might be 50% of nominal.

Let's use a Vbe margin of 5% or Vbe=630 mV or consult the datasheet for Vce(sat) max @ Ic=1mA

So I would use the Thevenin equivalents and 10% of hFE max ... to generate Ib=10% hFEmax I estimate by ...

**R1= (Vth-630mV) / 10% * hFE-max**   where Vth depends on R1,R3 ratio and Vdd of GPIO.

If all power was shared, a cap could be used instead of R3 if you wanted to conserve current to hold during a power off during a power on Reset (POR) to set GPIO as an output low.  Then the calculations are simple.  I generally use 30:1 for Rb/Rc if I don't need full saturation is using the same.

The effective resistance is Rce = Vce(sat)/Ic which will easily pull down the gate voltage with only 1.0 mA.

**But if I did no calculations** I would look at schematic and say simply use R1=10k unless you wanted to harvest energy. ;) and if no R3 & use R1=33k to 100k.

**- but then you can also raise R2 to gate for slightly slower switching to 100k and scale everything up.**.

Comment: The hFE of a transistor is used when it is an amplifier with always plenty of Vce, NEVER as a saturated switch. The datasheet for most transistors shows that it saturates well when its base current is 1/10th its collector current.

Comment: I think U misread @Audioguru  hFE is defined as Ic/Ib so this is just your semantic argument.  It is valid what I do. you can chose 10 % of hFE and get a reasonable result near Vce(sat) or make tradeoffs and use 30%. I don't mean for a 3: range in hFE use the min hFE but 30% of actual.